# Inertia group - local vs global field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification

In the case of a totally ramified extension of a complete field, then we know that there exist a maximum tamely ramified subextension, which is of degree coprime to $p$, and from that onward there are only wild ramification. Hence, if the extension is Galois, the inertia group (which is the whole Galois group), contains a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup.

I am not sure why every book I read on this only deal with local field (ie. complete valuation field). Is it simply not true for global field? I thought the same might be true for global field by some application of Krasner's lemma. But then again, none of the books mentioned that, so I am suspicious.

Comment: In a local field there is only one prime, so saying that the *extension* is ramified or tamely ramified makes sense. For a global field, it wouldn't make sense to say that the extension is (tamely) ramified. You could say that the extension is (tamely) ramified at some prime... but that is exactly same as saying that the extension obtained by localising at the prime is (tamely) ramified.

Comment: I am no expert in algebraic number theory, but I think that normally (specially following Neukirch's ANT) authors present global stuff first, like decomposition of the prime ideals in finite Galois extensions, and while at this point, is not easy to prove the existence of a $p$-Sylow subgroup of the inertia group. Then, when they pass to the local case, they do the valuation analogues and show that everything "valuation vs prime ideal" is actually the same. In the local case then its possible to prove such fact, and things automatically are true for the global case. I'm not sure though!

Comment: @Mathmo123: indeed, you have to pick a prime, but all other notions make sense. Of course, saying that it is tamely ramified at a prime is the same as saying that the local field have a tamely ramified extension. The problem is, all the local result about ramification, I am not sure if it carry about: for example, tamely ramification give a polynomial, but coefficients might be in the local field but not global field. And I am not sure what happen to the Galois group.

Comment: @user292595 if you have a Galois extension of global fields $L/K$ and a prime $\mathfrak q\subset\mathcal O_L$ above a prime$\mathfrak p\subset\mathcal O_K$, then you can decompose the extension into $L/L^{D_{\mathfrak{q/p}}}/K$ where $D$ is the decomposition group. The Galois group of $L/L^D$ is exactly the Galois group of the completions, so everything that can be said about the Galois group of the local extension can be said about the decomposition group of $L/K$